# How to capture ">>>" prompt in Python run as a C# Process

Tags: python, c#, .net

I have a small C# sample (.NET 8) that crudely recreates the Python interpreter by starting Python as a separate process and redirecting stdio to a StreamWriter and redirecting stdout and stderr to event handlers. I then take input from my console and feed it into the Python process via the StreamWriter, while displaying the output I receive from Python in the console via Console.WriteLine() calls in the event handlers. This is a dumb app on its own but it's some groundwork for a more involved project I would like to do. Along the way I discovered something I don't understand.

Shown below is a console session in this "Python interpreter". You can see that the usual ">>>" prompt doesn't appear where you would expect. Similarly with the "..." prompt you get when defining a function in the interpreter. However, when I write something invalid and trigger stderr, I can see that these ">>>" and "..." were apparently buffered somewhere and all come out over stderr at once.

Does anybody understand why this would be the case and how I can prevent this? And by "prevent" I mean trigger those prompts to be output when expected and not buffered somewhere? Does anybody know where and why they are buffered?

Console session (the lines NOT beginning with [stdout] or [stderr] were manually typed by me):

```
[stderr] Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
[stderr] Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
print("Hello")
[stdout] Hello
a = 12
print(a)
[stdout] 12
def sayHi():
    print("Hi!")

sayHi()
[stdout] Hi!
invalidpython
[stderr] >>> >>> >>> >>> ... ... >>> >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
[stderr]   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
[stderr] NameError: name 'invalidpython' is not defined
stop

C:\...\PyProcessDemo\PyProcessDemo\bin\Debug\net8.0\PyProcessDemo.exe (process 13732) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Full code sample:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new();
processStartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
processStartInfo.Arguments = "-i";
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

using Process process = new();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[stdout] {e.Data}");
});

process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[stderr] {e.Data}");
});

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput;

// Enter the "interpreter"
while(true)
{
    // Grab the next line. If null for some reason, ignore it and try another iteration.
    string? line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) continue;

    // Special code to end the program
    if (string.Equals(line, "stop")) break;

    // Send the line to Python
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}

// Clean up
process.Kill();
```

The project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Tried hooking events up to stdout and stderr to ensure anything coming over those streams would be displayed immediately. I was expecting the ">>>" prompt to be fed after every new statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after asking, it's actually pretty simple. Events aren't raised on the stderr and stdout listeners until those streams receives a newline. Naturally no newlines come along with the ">>>" and "..." prompt.

Here's a modified code snippet where infinitely-running threads just mash the Read() method on those streams and voila I get the prompts. Yes, those threads' outputs can collide, this is not a workable solution. Which brings me to my follow-up: does anybody know a workable solution to this?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new();
processStartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
processStartInfo.Arguments = "-i";
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

using Process process = new();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

process.Start();
StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput;

Thread stdErrThread = new(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        int c = process.StandardError.Read();
        Console.Write((char)c);
    }
});

Thread stdOutThread = new(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        int c = process.StandardOutput.Read();
        Console.Write((char)c);
    }
});

stdErrThread.Start();
stdOutThread.Start();

// Enter the "interpreter"
while (true)
{
    // Grab the next line. If null for some reason, ignore it and try another iteration.
    string? line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) continue;

    // Special code to end the program
    if (string.Equals(line, "stop")) break;

    // Send the line to Python
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}

// Clean up
process.Kill();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).